# How to subnet a network given a range of usable hosts?

Tags: networking, subnet

Sorry if this is a strange or noob question.

How would you go about finding the subnet mask for a network if you are already restricted to a certain number of host numbers on the network? For example, how would I go about subnetting the network into 4 if I could only use x.x.x.1-150? Is there a specific method to do this or would I just use a /27 subnet mask so that the usable range has 4 subnets in it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, if you are limited to the range 0-150, and would need 4 subnets, they would need to be /27. Then you have the subnets .0 to .31; .32 to .63; .64 to .95; .96 to .127. The next subnet (.128 - .159) does not fall completely in your allowed range anymore, so shouldn't be used.

All ranges listed by network id and broadcast address. Those numbers should not be used, but everything between them is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should think in the terms of binary logic, it should make things easier with time.

You have 150 IP addresses, which should be divided into the four subnets.
Then you have 37 addresses for each subnet, and nearest number is 2^5 = 32 IP addresses.

Then subnet mask required is 32 - 5 = /27

Sorry, it can be overwhelming but it just obvious for me and hard to explain too.

Regards.

Comment: This is precisely the same answer already given and accepted several months ago. Please avoid repeating answers already given and focus on giving good unique answers.